How to make a map of the world without political borders and only coastal borders?
I am looking to make a heatmap in R displaying the diversity of islands around the world, but I'm having difficulty finding the right way to do this. I have made heatmaps before of states in the US and countries in the world with the ggplot2 and maps packages, but this time I cannot find the right template to use. The boundaries in the heatmap really need to be based on natural geography, and not political geography. For example, islands like Hispaniola and Borneo need to be one entity (as opposed to 2 or 3 countries), and islands like Java and Sumatra need to be separate entities (as opposed to just a single country). If such a template does not exist, is there any way to do this manually?
I tried using the ggplot2 default world map to create my heatmap, but I wasn't able to split up/combine countries to display the actual information I wanted.
plot1 <-ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=species))+
  geom_path()+ 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(heat.colors(50)),na.value="grey90")+
  coord_map()

I used this code to actually construct the heatmaps, which I believe should be correct. My problem is changing the boundaries.
The figure should look something like this. Here the authors use river drainage basins to assign different regions on the heatmap. I only need individual islands for my heatmap.

You will probably want to find a shapefile online for the islands you need and use the sf package to load the file and draw the map.

As Eonema says, it's best to identify the islands you will need and then which countries exercise political jurisdiction over part of or all of each island. I'd also recommend using the rnaturalearth package instead of the default ggplot2 world map, because 1) it automatically imports the world map as an sf object, so you can take advantage of the more powerful ggplot2::geom_sf() over geom_polygon() and 2) you can use sf functions on it, such as sf::st_union(), which for instance would allow you to combine Haiti and the DR into Hispaniola by dissolving their borders.

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a combination of the coastline and countries datasets from the rnaturalearth package. Neither data have specific island attributes for all of the islands you mention, but for your use case, it does not matter.
This example uses the least-detailed resolution of both datasets, which is OK if your mapping at full world extent. If you need a finer resolution, change small to either medium or large. You may be prompted to install another rnaturalearth package for the more detailed versions.
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Load countries and coastline sf data
countries <- ne_countries(scale = "small")
coast <- ne_coastline(scale = "small")

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = countries, colour = "lightgrey", fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_sf(data = coast, colour = "grey50") +
  theme_void()


To illustrate further, here's what Borneo looks like close up at small resolution:
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = countries, colour = "lightgrey", fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_sf(data = coast, colour = "grey50") +
  labs(title = "Borneo") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(107, 120),
           ylim = c(-5, 7)) +
  theme_void()


